# Не могу запустить MariaDB с терминала

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, mariadb, xampp

Установил XAMPP. При запуске команды:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

apache и mariadb запускаются нормально. Заходить можно даже в **PhpMyAdmin**.
При этом, если через терминал попытаться зайти через команду:

```
mysql -u username -pPassword
```

то пишет

> error 2002 hy000 can't connect to local mysql server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 2

Пробовал выключить xampp и так попробовать, не помогает. Через `sudo service mysql start` пишет, что такого сервиса нет. Что делать?

Comment: Ну поищи мариевский сокет по другому адресу. Может он в `/run` лежит или типа того.

Comment: Посмотрите настройки подключения в `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась достаточно прозаичной: нужно просто перейти на `/opt/lampp/bin` и там c помощью команды `./mysql -uUser -pPassword` можно зайти на локальный сервер MariaDB.